# moved /home folder into subfolder of /root, when logged as root

Tags: root, home-directory

I did a mistake, I was logged as root and I moved the home folder accidentally. 
I don't have a GUI as I am running on a Openstack virtual machine setup by someone else. I can't boot from a LiveUSB and move it back.

Here is what it looks like

- ....

  - (here there should be home)
  - root

    - mydirectoryname *(this used to be the `home`folder)*

      - mydirectoryname *(it has the same name as its parent. I don't care if i loose what is inside)*
      - Ubuntu

Please, help me get things as this again:

- ....

  - home

    - Ubuntu
  - root

Which command should I execute ?
Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Why not boot from a LiveUSB and move it back?

Comment: Im using a virtual machine openstack at my company, I cannot do that...

Comment: Then [edit] your question and give a full description of the  problem. Now it is very unclear.

Comment: And what is the problem to move the directory back?

Comment: I don't know what command to execute. I really don't want to do a mistake... Could you help me ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
mv /root/mydirectoryname /home
```

Comment: Do I need to be in a specific folder to execute this ?

Comment: It does not matter. I used absolute path.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Didn't want to get killed for my first week of internship